Navigation in BI
To provide navigation in power bi ,through the cell of table visual,that when it clicks it will navigate to another page & show me the drilled down data.
when the cell is clicked it will navigate to another page & show me the drilled down data respective to that selection

One-click drillthroughs are currently not supported as far as I know
